# QAbstractItemModel checkboxes are not checkable

Tags: qtreeview, pyside6, qabstractitemmodel

Why are the checkboxes in my TreeView not checkable?
I think there is an issue with the index() and parent() methods, but do not know how to fix it.
setData() also never called...

Any help is really appreciated...

```py
import logging
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel, QPersistentModelIndex

class DBObject:
    def __init__(self, name, parent, children=None, is_checkable=False):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children or list()
        self.is_checkable = is_checkable

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"name: {self.name}, parent: {self.parent.name if self.parent is not None else '-'}"


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._root = DBObject("root", None)
        self.newData()
        self.checks = {}

    def checkState(self, index):
        if index in self.checks.keys():
            return self.checks[index]
        else:
            return QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked

    def newData(self):
        items = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
        for x in items:
            child = DBObject(x + "0", self._root)
            self._root.children.append(child)
            for y in items:
                child.children.append(DBObject(y + "1", child, None, True))

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            return 1

        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()
        rowCount = len(parentItem.children)
        logging.info(f"rowCount({parentItem}): rowCount={rowCount}")
        return rowCount

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        item = index.internalPointer()
        parentItem = item.parent

        logging.info(f"parent({item}): parent={parentItem}")
        if parentItem is None:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        else:
            if parentItem.parent is None:
                return self.createIndex(0, 0, parentItem)
            else:
                return self.createIndex(parentItem.parent.children.index(parentItem), 0, parentItem)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            if row != 0 or column != 0:
                return QtCore.QModelIndex()
            else:
                logging.info(f"index({row}, {column}, None): index={self._root}")
                return self.createIndex(0, 0, self._root)

        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        if 0 <= row < len(parentItem.children):
            logging.info(f"index({row}, {column}, {parentItem}): index={parentItem.children[row]}")
            return self.createIndex(row, column, parentItem.children[row])
        else:
            logging.info(f"index({row}, {column}, {parentItem}): index=None")
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()

        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        item = index.internalPointer()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole and col == 0 and item.is_checkable:
            return QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked

        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return item.name
        else:
            return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole):

        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole:
            self.checks[QPersistentModelIndex(index)] = value
            return True
        return False


class ProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFilterKeyColumn(0)
        self.setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(True)

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.NoItemFlags

        return (
                QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled
                | QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)

        self._treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        layout.addWidget(self._treeView)

        self._model = Model()
        self._proxyModel = ProxyModel()
        self._proxyModel.setSourceModel(self._model)
        self._treeView.setModel(self._proxyModel)

        # self._proxyModel.setFilterFixedString("bar1")

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add")
        layout.addWidget(button)

        button.clicked.connect(self._Clicked)

    def _Clicked(self):
        self._model.newData()
        self._treeView.expandAll()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various issues with your code:

- the most important one is that you're not returning the `ItemIsUserCheckable` flag;
- you're overriding the `flag()` in the proxy model (uselessly, by the way, since you're just returning the default flags of QAbstractItemModel);
- `data()` always returns `Checked` no matter its value;
- `setData()` should *always* emit `dataChanged` (as the documentation points out);
- it's not really clear why you return a QModelIndex() if the top level item has row or column greater than 0;

Change the `flag()` behavior of the source model, remove that of the proxy (or implement it *properly*, using the default implementation), and correct both `data()` and `setData()`.

```py
class Model(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._root = DBObject("root", None)
        self.newData()
        self.checks = {}

    def newData(self):
        items = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
        for x in items:
            child = DBObject(x + "0", self._root)
            self._root.children.append(child)
            for y in items:
                child.children.append(DBObject(y + "1", child, None, True))

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super().flags(index)
        item = index.internalPointer()
        if item and item.is_checkable:
            flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
        return flags

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            return 1

        return len(parent.internalPointer().children)

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        item = index.internalPointer()
        parentItem = item.parent

        if parentItem is None:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if parentItem.parent is None:
            return self.createIndex(0, 0, parentItem)
        else:
            return self.createIndex(
                parentItem.parent.children.index(parentItem), 0, parentItem)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            if row != 0 or column != 0:
                return QtCore.QModelIndex()
            else:
                return self.createIndex(0, 0, self._root)

        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        if 0 <= row < len(parentItem.children):
            return self.createIndex(row, column, parentItem.children[row])

        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        item = index.internalPointer()
        col = index.column()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole and col == 0 and item.is_checkable:
            return self.checks.get(QPersistentModelIndex(index), QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item.name

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False

        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            pIndex = QPersistentModelIndex(index)
            if self.checks.get(pIndex) != value:
                self.checks[pIndex] = value
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                return True

        return False
```

Also:

- consider that models **must** be as fast as possible, so you should avoid unnecessary variable definitions (unless they *really* help coding and readability) and improve code logic;
- avoid unnecessary `else:` blocks that are implicit in the function flow (especially if used to just `return None` at the end of a function);

Comment: Thank you...to be honest i forgot to write that this was an example i found on SO. It was my fault that i mixed up the ItemIsUserCheckable and ItemIsSelectable. Could you please elaborate more on the index() and parent() methods? maybe i can fix then the QModelIndex() returns... The other tips are really great, thanks again

Comment: What do you need me to elaborate about `index()` and `parent()`?

Comment: just meant i want to know what to return from both methods... you mentioned that this is not understandable? if row != 0 or column != 0:
                return QtCore.QModelIndex()

Comment: Well, it's conceptually valid in your specific case, with only a *single* top level item, but that shouldn't go there (or at least, not like that). Consider that, normally, the *real* root is actually a hidden *unique* element, and this is conceptually valid also for Qt models. What you're calling "Root" is actually a top level item, not the *actual* root (which, instead, always has an invalid index, as in -1 for both row and columns) at least as it's normally intended for a tree-like structure.